# How to print stack trace of a thread (with thread id) via bash command?

Tags: multithreading, bash, stack-trace, jstack, printstacktrace

I would try to monitor the action performed on a  thread something like `tail` command. And it should print the `stackTrace` of the thread (whose thread id is known).

I could print the stack trace of all the threads which is currently running under the java process like the following

```
pid=$(ps -ef |grep 'catalina' | grep java | awk ' { print $2 } ');
eval '/home/jdk/bin/jstack -F $pid' > stack_trace.txt
```

But I need to print stack trace of the thread whose thread id is known.

Any help in this  regard is most welcome. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well,  I would assume that you have the information you need already in the file stack_trace.txt, so dig a bit more and then you get the answer :)

Comment: @KrassiEm It's available already in that file. But number of active thread is too large - it's just getting all the threads which are currently running under the java process... So, It would be a great relief if i could get the stack trace of the current thread alone or live stack trace (something like the tail does) - getting the active changes going on..

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file on github, only if you allowed to. It seems once the file is there, some regular expressions parsing should be used to extract the thing that you need. I am sure some grep, awk, perl code is a step away from the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to see if below works for you.

```
TARGET_THREAD_ID=xxx JAVA_PID=$(ps -ef | grep "[org].apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap"  | awk '{print $2}'); jstack -F ${JAVA_PID} | sed -n -e "/Thread ${TARGET_THREAD_ID}/,/Thread /p" | head -n -1
```

Which will print something like below

```
Thread xxx: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=502 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(boolean) @bci=54, line=191 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=1, line=153 (Compiled frame)
```